# Node doesn't find local packages

Tags: node.js, npm

I'm learning node. I've initialized a project with npm. I installed express, and everything looks alright.

npm list outputs this:

[image]

package.json looks like this:

[image]

And the project is structured like this:

[image]

with index.js just being the following:

```
const expressDep = require('express');
const app = express();
```

But when I try to execute index.js, node outputs the following:

[image]

What am I doing wrong ?
To my understanding, node just doesn't see any definition of express, but npm tells me everything is installed correctly. What's going on ?

Comment: change `const app = express()` to `const app = expressDep()` . tips, read the error message first and identify what's wrong with your code. in your case you call `express()` while `express` is not defined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How can the compiler know what is this express()?

Require is a built-in function to include external modules that exist in separate files.

If you want to use this app function you must use the variable you assigned the module. Like this:

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
```

or

```
const expressDep = require("express");
const app = expressDep();
```

Comment: God I feel so dumb. Thank you kind sir.